# How to store result of hive query in a variable?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm new to hive. trying to create a hive script.
i used below command in a hive script but result of query is not getting stored in variable.

```
set hivevar:var1=(show create table table7);

echo var1;
```

is this correct way of doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure you can store a create table statement as a string within Hive itself. What's the use case? Can you use a Hive client like Java or Python?

Comment: @OneCricketeer i'm trying to write a script to migrate a list of tables from one environment cluster to another.

Comment: There's a tool called CircusTrain on Github that does something like that. Otherwise, as mentioned,  you could use a JDBC client in Java rather than hiveql scripts which will only have access to one environment's hiveserver